# how to get the count value based on comparing string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript, object

I have array object in which I compare each string in a array and if one letter is not matching, increment the value. If three characters match with the string then increment the count value, else 0

```js
var obj = ["race", "sack", "grass", "brass", "beat", "pack", "cake"]

fucntion getValue(obj) {
    var count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= obj.length; j++) {
        if (obj[i].split("") == obj[j].split("") {
            count++;
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

Expected Output

```
race 1 
sack 2 // (pack, cake matches 3 letters with sack so 2) 
grass 1
brass 1
beat 0
pack 2
cake 3
```

Comment: Can you give a clearer description of the problem, and explain your expected output. I don't see how `sack` = 2, yet `race` = 0, given that you match `pack` and `cake` on the `a` and `c` in the original values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for reply, compare each string, if all characters same but off by one character then increment the count, for example sack => pack, cake

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan update the output, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object for output,
parse through each element in the array, replace characters from comparing elements.
check if at least 3 chars got removed if so +1 to respective element.

```js
const arr = ["race", "sack", "grass", "brass", "beat", "pack", "cake"];
const out = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(e => [e, 0]));
for(i in arr) {
  for(j in arr) {
    if(i == j) continue;
    if(arr[i].length !== arr[j].length) continue;
    const res = [...arr[i]].reduce((acc, e)=> acc.replace(e, ''), arr[j]);
    if(res.length <= arr[j].length - 3) {
      out[arr[i]] = out[arr[i]] + 1
    }
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but for the input `["race", "beat", "grass", "brass", "sabre", "pack","back","chat", "cabs","saga"]` should return `{
  back: 2,
  beat: 0,
  brass: 2,
  cabs: 1,
  chat: 0,
  grass: 1,
  pack: 1,
  race: 0,
  sabre: 1,
  saga: 0
}`

Comment: @miyavv how `beat` is 0 when it matches `bea` in `sabre`?

Comment: thanks for reply, length should be same, forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSameCount(str1, str2) {
  let count = 0;
  const obj = str2.split("");
  for(str of str1){
    let idx = obj.findIndex(s => s === str);
    if(idx >= 0){
      count++;
      obj.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }
  return count;
}


var obj = ["race", "sack", "grass", "brass", "beat", "pack", "cake"]

const res = {}

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    res[obj[i]] = 0
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            matchCount = getSameCount(obj[i], obj[j])

            if (matchCount === 3) {
                res[obj[i]]++
            } else {
                if (obj[i].length - matchCount == 1) {
                    res[obj[i]]++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for `['aaa', 'aab']` if `[0, 0]` is expected

Comment: @Nitin Goyal thanks for reply, if i pass array as  ["race", "beat", "grass", "brass", "sabre", "pack","back","chat", "cabs","saga"] returns wrong output, race should be 0 `, output should be  back: 2,
  beat: 0,
  brass: 2,
  cabs: 1,
  chat: 0,
  grass: 1,
  pack: 1,
  race: 0,
  sabre: 1,
  saga: 0